# Reading in a matrix from textile with Python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I'm new to python and am trying to get familiar with its library capabilities

Let's say I have a file name cases_test.txt where the contents look like:

```
cases: 2 
matrix size: 5 x 5

case #1 matrix:

       x.     v.     t.    u.     w.  
x      0.5    0.6    1.2   2.0    1.3 
v      0.7    0.8    1.0   3.0    0.3 
t      0.4    0.3    0.7   0.1    0.6 
u      1.2    3.2    0.2   2.9    1.9 
w      0.2    0.5    0.9   0.3    1.7


case #2 matrix:

       x.    v.     t.    u.     w.  
x     1.8    0.9    0.0   1.3    1.4 
v     0.5    0.5    2.3   3.3    0.1 
t     1.3    0.3    0.7   0.1    0.2 
u     1.7    3.9    2.5   1.2    1.3 
w     0.1    0.2    0.9   0.3    1.1

variables: 5
```

I have the following so far:

```
def read_file(text_File):

    file = open(text_File, "r") #open file for reading
    
    stuff = [] #empty list to hold contents after "case #1 matrix" 
   
    for line in file: 
    #For in is used to loop through lines in a file
        if 'case #1 matrix:' in line:
            print("At matrix one\n") 
              ##Reached matrix one
            stuff.append = ([list(line) for contents in line.split()])
            if 'case #2 matrix:' in line: 
                print("At matrix two\n") 
                ##Breaks when the next matrix is encountered 
                break
    print(stuff)
    print("Contents in list stuff printed")      
   
    return stuff
```

Eventually, I want to extract the matrix from my list "stuff" to then store as float values in a separate list. Any tips on how to approach this would help. Thank you!

Comment: there is an indentation error for case #2, the way you write it its only executed if the line already contains case #1

also you only effectively append the line with case #1 to stuff and ignore all other lines

Answer (score 0):

This line is not correct:

```
stuff.append = ([list(line) for contents in line.split()])
```

Try this instead:

```
stuff.append = (line.split())
```

After that, you can change items to float.
(If you provide some sample of your expected output, I could help with that)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not too familiar with python syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the output should exactly look like but this one will store all the data at least and you can modify it to whatever it should look like

```
def read_file(text_File):
    stuff = {}
    cur_matrix = ''

    with open(text_File) as fp:
        for line in fp.readlines():
            if 'case #1 matrix:' in line:
                cur_matrix = 1
                print("At matrix one\n")
                continue
            if 'case #2 matrix:' in line:
                cur_matrix = 2 
                print("At matrix two\n") 
                continue

            if cur_matrix != '':
                if line.strip() != '':
                    stuff.setdefault(cur_matrix, []).append(
                        [x for x in line.split() if x.strip() != '']
                    )

        print(stuff)
        print("Contents in list stuff printed")      
   
    return stuff


read_file('file.txt')
```

I parses the file line by line, doing so you have to remember in which case block you are to store it in the correct dictionary value.

Also for the parsing

```
  stuff.setdefault(cur_matrix, []).append(
       [x for x in line.split() if x.strip() != '']
  )
```

you might want to exclude any kind of empty spaces otherwise you have to create special cases for those later on

Comment: Thank you! This has been helpful.